# Alternative to returning dictionaries instead of tuples from user-defined functions

Tags: python, dictionary, return

I frequently find myself returning dictionaries instead of tuples when defining functions in Python with many outputs (say 5-20).  For example, I may define a function with many outputs:

```
def my_fun_conventional(a,b,c):
    sum_ = a+b+c
    prod_ = a*b*c
    return a, b, c, sum_, prod_
```

I like to return a dictionary instead, which lets me access the output differently.

```
def my_fun_dict(a,b,c):
    sum_ = a+b+c
    prod_ = a*b*c

    return {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'sum': sum_, 'prod': prod_}

    output = my_fun_dict(1,2,3)
    output['sum']
```

I often prefer the second function for two reasons: (1) I don't have to worry about conflicting names in `globals` and (2) I don't have to worry about making sure that the order of returned objects and assigned names line up perfectly; if I change the order I specify key-value pairs in the dictionary, it doesn't matter. The latter reason is particularly relevant for rapid development when I am constantly changing the output of the functions, and since I am an NLP researcher, I am mostly in development.

However, I don't see other people returning dictionaries.  This leads me to believe I am doing something inadvisable.  So my first question is: Is there something inadvisable about returning dictionaries as I do?  If so, is there a nice way to achieve the two goals discussed above?

If what I do is not inadvisable, I have a follow-up question: It is annoying to have to type each variable name twice in the dictionary (once for the key, once for the value)—is there some way to do this in a nicer way?  I'm envisioning some sort of utility function (say `output_dict`) that would do this

```
def my_fun_dict(a,b,c):
    sum_ = a+b+c
    prod_ = a*b*c

    return output_dict(a, b, c, sum_, prod_)
```

Again, it feels like there might be a pythonic alternative since I can't be the first person to deal with this issue.

Comment: How about using [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)?

Comment: 1, returning a dictionary is fine. 2, no, you can't define a dictionary without specifying key names in some manner. Slightly fewer keystrokes would be to use `return dict(a=a, b=b, c=c, sum=sum_, prod=prod_)`

Comment: The key value for your dictionary items need to defined whatsover. Assigning values to those keys through return statement as in your second solution is completely fine.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I didn't know about those!  They're interesting, but basically amount to the same keystroke repetition as a dictionary.  I'll keep them in mind for other uses though!

Comment: @ddejohn Removing the quotes would mean I would have to access the values by the values themselves, no?

Comment: Actually no! Using the `_=val` in `dict()` is literally just keyword arguments. The left-hand side is taken as a string. E.g., `x, y, z = 1, 2, 3; dict(x=x, y=y, z=z) -> {"x": 1, "y": 2, "z": 3}`.

Comment: @ddejohn indeed!

Comment: It appears that no one thinks my solution of using dictionaries is un-pythonic or inadvisable, so I'll consider this solved.  I was going to vote to close the question, but the reasons given indicated I was mistaken about the reasons to close a question.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: One tangential suggestion: If you don't always use each part of the output (e.g. say for a particular output you use the `output['sum']`, but not `output['prod']`, then there is one optimization you can make to avoid wasteful calculations. Your dictionary values can be `lambda`s. E.g. change `sum_ = a + b + c` to `sum_ = lambda: a + b + c` and likewise for `prod_`. Now you can trigger the sum calculation by doing `output['sum']()`, but you won't ever trigger the prod calculation unless you call it. A downside is that each time you do `output['sum']()` you'll be triggering the calculation.

Comment: One potential other idea I could imagine would be to return a `class`, e.g. define `class myclass(): pass` and then in your function, `output=myclass()` followed by `output.a = a`, `output.b=b`, etc. But then you're stuck with the whole thing, and you couldn't do something like `x = my_fun_dict(1,2,3)['sum']`.

Comment: @wikikikitiki I believe that uses the object's (i.e. class instance's) `__dict__` [1], so it's still using a `dict`, just in a more roundabout way. User defined functions also have a `__dict__` for writable attributes [2], so if OP goes this route, they can use a dummy class as you suggested or a dummy function. See: [1] https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__dict__#object.__dict__ and [2] https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__dict__

Comment: @joseville, you're right! It didn't occur to me in the moment. Thanks.

Comment: @joseville that is actually a very common situation for me.

Comment: @BioBroo how expensive are the calculations? If not too expensive, then it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: If they are expensive, then using lambda's will prevent your code from doing unnecessary expensive calculations. I mentioned a downside, but there is a workaround. The first time you need a particular key of your output (e.g. `'sum'`), do `output['sum'] = output['sum']()`. On the right hand side, it retrieves the lambda, executes it to get a value. It then assigns that value back into `output['sum']`, so that you don't have to execute the lambda again. Subsequently, if you need the calculated value again, you can do `ouput['sum']`.

Comment: There is a 3. advantage: with dictionaries, you can change the number of return values without needing to care about function call in the code, e.g. if you increase form 2 to 3 returned values, you would need to change from
val, _ = my_func()
to
val,  _  ,_   = my_func()
wherever it is called. 
You would need this also with named tuoles, but not with dictionaries.